# Decoder upsample size

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, autoencoder

I have a simple autoencoder which looks like this:

```
class Autoencoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()

        self.channels = [3, 8, 16, 32]

        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
                # layer 1
                nn.Conv2d(self.channels[0], self.channels[1], 3, 1, 1),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(self.channels[1]),
                nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
                nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=4, stride=4),
                # layer 2
                nn.Conv2d(self.channels[1], self.channels[2], 3, 1, 1),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(self.channels[2]),
                nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
                nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=4, stride=4),
                # layer 3
                nn.Conv2d(self.channels[2], self.channels[3], 3, 1, 1),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(self.channels[3]),
                nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
                nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
            )
        
        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Conv2d(self.channels[3], self.channels[2], 3, 1, 1),                
                nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
                nn.Upsample(size=(15, 20), mode='bilinear', align_corners=False),

                nn.Conv2d(self.channels[2], self.channels[1], 3, 1, 1),                
                nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
                nn.Upsample(scale_factor=4, mode='bilinear', align_corners=False),

                nn.Conv2d(self.channels[1], 1, 1),                
                nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
                nn.Upsample(scale_factor=4, mode='bilinear', align_corners=False)
            )

    def forward(self, x):
        h = self.encoder(x)
        y = self.decoder(h)
        return y
```

Can someone clarify if the `nn.Upsample(size=(15, 20)...` in the Decoder has something to do with restoring the images to their original dimensions? My input images(torch tensors) are of size 240*320 and the network is supposed to restore the input tensor to its original size.

Also if I add a fourth layer to my encoder with 64 channels and a 4th layer to my decoder (similar to the layers above), what should the upsampling size be in the first layere of the decode?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please **re-read** [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and notice that questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for SO (removed your last question, otherwise this would be eligible for closure as a resource request).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [PyTorch Documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Upsample.html), You may define an upsampling layer with a scale factor or an output size. Stating `output_size=(H, W)` will make sure the output size will be `(H, W)`, regardless of the input size. On the other hand, stating `scale_factor=4` will make sure the output of each spatial dimension will be 4 times the input, e.g. `(30, 40) -> (120, 160)`.

You want to mention you need to get an output of size `240 * 320`. Therefore, the spatial dimensions of your output from the decoder will be `(15*4*4, 20*4*4)` which conveniently is `(240, 320)`.